# reading lines from stdin in python?

Tags: python

So I need to do a for each loop where it reads each line in stdin and then prints L. Now L is the variable that's supposed to represent the line however I'm not sure how to declare that? What I'm doing right now is:

```
import sys
for L in sys.stdin:
    print L
```

But does python recognize that L is supposed be each line in stdin?

Comment: Yes... that's what iterating over a file does.

Comment: Yep, you can call it whatever you want as long as it doesn't start with numbers or punctuation marks. `L` is fine. Also, you can read lines from stdin like you're doing. Side note, you should indent your code (move `for L in sys.stdin: print L` four spaces to the left)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sys.stdin` is a `TextIOWrapper` which has new line control. It can be `None`,`""`,`\n`, and `\r\n`.